# how to stop the execution of the jquery function

Tags: jquery

Hello I've got a function which on each keyup event test if the length of the value of the input is ==3 and if so calls another function;

My problem is   that I want when the length is >3   to stop the execution of this jquery function

```
$('#txtInput').bind('keyup', lil);
```

I tried with unbind but it doesn't work; Thanks in advance

```
 var lil = function () 
             {
              var  strin = document.getElementById('txtInput').value;
              newstr = strin.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04FF0-9]/gi, '');
              alert (newstr);
              k = newstr.length;
             if (newstr.length==3)
             {triming();}



             }

$(function() 
{
     $('#txtInput').bind('keyup', lil);     

       /*if (k>3)
       $("txtInput").unbind("keyup", lil);  */ - this doesn't work



});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of unbinding event just use return statement to stop further execution of code in the function.

```
if (k>3)  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your code to unbind the event handler is run only once when the page loads and the variable k is still undefined. You need to check if k > 3 every time the keyup handler has done its work:

```
var lil = function () 
{
    var  strin = document.getElementById('txtInput').value;
    var newstr = strin.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04FF0-9]/gi, '');
    alert (newstr);
    var k = newstr.length;
    if (k==3){
         triming();
    }
    if (k>3)
        $("txtInput").unbind("keyup", lil); 

$(function() 
{
    $('#txtInput').bind('keyup', lil);     
});
```

Also, you are binding the function lil to the keyup event twice, the first time most likely before the document has been parsed by the browser. Keep only the second binding that is wrapped in the (implicit) $(document).ready() function.

Note also that I made newstr and k local variables by preceding them with "var". You may want to undo that if you really need them to be global.